# Calculating MaxTimeUuid and MinTimeUuid in C#

Tags: c#, cassandra

I'm trying to:

a) Generate timeuuids from a C# DateTime

b) Get the DateTime back from a given timeuuid

c) Find the MaxTimeUuid and MinTimeUuid for a given DateTime

---

For a) and b) I've found [this link](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/src/Cassandra/TimeUuid.cs) which provides me a struct with the required functionality.

For c) I've found [this link](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/src/Cassandra/Data/Linq/CqlFunction.cs) which seems to have the functions, but they just return null, so it looks like it's not been implemented yet.

Is this the case?

Is there C# functionality anywhere that I can create a max and min timeuuid for a given time?

Thank you

Comment: Check this test code https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/src/Cassandra.IntegrationTests/CqlFunctions/Tests/MaxTimeUuid.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The DataStax C# driver provides those methods in the TimeUuid structure](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.2/html/T_Cassandra_TimeUuid.htm):

- Use [`TimeUuid.GetDate()`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.2/html/M_Cassandra_TimeUuid_GetDate.htm) to retrieve the timestamp from a given `TimeUuid`.
- Use [`TimeUuid.NewId(DateTimeOffset)`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.2/html/M_Cassandra_TimeUuid_NewId_2.htm) static method to generate a timeuuid from a given timestamp.

About max and min timeuuid methods, those are not yet available on the C# side. You can use those from CQL: `SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE id = ? and time >= minTimeuuid(?)`.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html

Comment: Thank you. Is there a likelihood that we'll see the max and min being added to the c# driver anytime soon?

Comment: @Blootac I've just created a ticket for it :) https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-556